# Is silverlight the right choice of technology for enterprise applications after Microsoft's comments in PDC 2010

Tags: silverlight

We were beginning to start on an enterprise application using silverlight.

However after reading [this post](http://techcrunch.com/2010/10/30/rip-silverlight-on-the-web/) we doubt whether it is the right choice going forward.

> The post says that, according to
>   Microsoft's declaration in PDC 2010,
>   Microsoft has changed their strategy
>   regarding silverlight and they no
>   longer view it as their technology to
>   deliver cross platform applications.
>   Instead they are targeting silverlight
>   as their development platform for
>   Windows phone 7.

Is this correct? Should we still continue with silverlight or go back to ASP.NET WebForms\MVC?

The Scope of the application is basically intranet with Windows 2008 servers and Windows XP and Windows 7 clients. However a subset of functionality needs to be available to the external users over the internet. There we cannot have any restrictions on what OS users can use.

Comment: What exactly is the scope of your enterprise application? Do you need to target multiple operating systems, or is "primarily Windows, but checking it works on Mac and Linux too" okay?

Comment: Updated the question with the scope of the application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on the info you gave, I can't conclude whether silverlight is the way to go. But what I do know is that a number of Microsofties wrote some blogposts about the things said about Silverlight on the pdc. For example [John Papa](http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/committed-to-silverlight/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+JohnPapa+%28JohnPapa.net%29), [Bob Muglia](http://team.silverlight.net/announcement/pdc-and-silverlight/) and [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/04/silverlight-questions.aspx).

**Update about the scope**
I think you already gave the answer when you described the scope of the application. A part of the application will be available to external users and you cannot have any restriction about the OS they are running. With that requirement I think Silverlight is not the best way to go. Not because the rumours about its future but because of its platform indepency. What are the reasons **not** to go for a ASP.NET/web solution? Silverlight doesn't work on each OS whereas plain HTML will work everywhere. (ok you need a descent browser) 
Although for a good advice I'd need more information about the application.

Comment: +1 for the link to the bob muglia retraction blog post.  its important to know that it was a big enough error of a statement for the guy who made it to actually come out and post a retraction.

Comment: I, at the moment, was more interested in knowing how Microsoft looks at it. We will have more debates about whether we should use it or not depending upon our needs but thanks for providing the links. This helps.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the question you have to ask yourself is this: do you need your application to be used on *every* platform, i.e. Windows, Mac, Linux, misc. flavors of Unix, IPhone and other mobile platforms?
If that's the case, then a web based solution is the way to go.

If Windows, Mac and partially Linux is enough, then save yourself and your team a lot of pain and use Silverlight.

In my opinion support for mobile clients is the key factor in your decision.

Comment: In the same time, it's important not to believe that an HTML web apps will be enough for all platforms: Often, the best way to go for mobile platforms is the phone app. (Mainly because it's rare that the same UI can be used across such different screen sizes).

Answer (score 1):

For sure the right platform for Intranet, Enterprice applications Is **Silverlight**. It is 
**stable**, **performs extreamly well**, the environment and the **development time is huuge less than web application development**, the end User Experience is much better and so on and so forth... Once you want to show part of the system out the the intranet - just create some specific target modules that will address the needed audince. You won't have the universal "Reachfull" solution, that will target everyhing, you'll always need mobile versions or other devices and so on. But once you've built your project the right way with Services (same services that the Silverlight app will consume), it'll be easy job to consume them with new UI.
Hope you will choose Silverlihgt.

Comment: Why is Silverlight more stable than a Web app? And also why is the development time huge less? Can you show some testresults, or is it just because you're a big fan of Siverlight? ;-)

Comment: I've never said it's more stable, but it's stable. Anyway, the Silverlight platform guaranties you cross-browser support, while web apps. guaranties you Non-cross browser support! Which results in faster development and not fighting with the browser problems, also the programming model, the available tools for creating applications and so on are much better. ;)

Comment: I disagree; Silverlight is even less cross-platform compared to HTML. With IE8 (and especially 9) Microsoft supports the latest standards better, while the other browsers already support most of the recent standards. Silverlight works only on Windows and Mac. The Moonlight implentation is incomplete and not as up to date as Silverlight 4. Besides Expression, you need Visual Studio for silverlight apps, you can use vs.net as well for ASP.NET. Also Silverlight doesn't even run on WP7 phones (in the browser) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is a great technology, but the Microsoft does not develop it anymore. So as a technology is a great decision. But if you want to make a Silverlight app usable on a NOT supported platform (e.g. Android or iPhone) you have to use 3rd party services. For example http://sl2html.com